# How to install ecwid payment gateway template

Tags: wordpress, plugins, payment, gateway

I'm currently working on the wordpress **ecwid** plugin. In order to develop my own payment method, I downloaded on github their payment gateway template that I'm now trying to install on my wordpress **ecwid shop** without success. Please, would you know how to proceed? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

It's Gunter from Ecwid team. I see you reached out to us via email too. We've addressed the email request. And we will post the answer here too, just in case.

If you want to integrate a custom payment to your Ecwid store, you should follow these steps:

1. Register a custom app. You can do that at this direct link: https://my.ecwid.com/#develop-apps
2. Provide us with the payment URL (your own server) to which Ecwid will send the payment requests. You can send us your URL to apps@ecwid.com email and we'll add it to your app.

After that, when your customers choose your own payment at checkout and click on the “Pay” button, Ecwid will send a POST request with the cart data to your server payment URL. And your customer will be also redirected to this URL. So, you can show any external page to them after redirection.

After redirection, your server needs to get cart details from the request, decrypt it and send it to the payment provider in a correct format for processing. After the payment is processed, your server needs to update the order status and redirect the customers back to the Ecwid storefront.

You can find more details about how the custom payment apps work here: https://api-docs.ecwid.com/docs/how-payment-method-works